# Camera preview does not conform to UIView bounds when running on iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I have an issue when using a camera preview layer within an app. I am currently experiencing an issue where I need the camera preview to alter its size depending on the device its loading on (on iPhone SE the width 380, height 224 while on iPhone 6, 7, 8 its width 479, height 279 and so on in landscape mode). However, whenever I run the app on a device I am provided with the current frame from my storyboard whether this is landscape or portrait.

Screenshot of storyboard layout, all views have constraints:

[image: screenshot of storyboard layout, all views have constraints]

The following screenshots are taken from my iPhone6S running the app:

Storyboard set to landscape iPhone8+:

[image: storyboard set to landscape iPhone8+]

Storyboard set to landscape iPhone8:

[image: storyboard set to landscape iPhone8]

Storyboard set to landscape iPhoneSE:

[image: storyboard set to landscape iPhoneSE]

Storybaord set to portrait:

[image: storyboard set to portrait]

The code is taken from Zero2Launch's YouTube tutorial [Swift 4 & iOS 11: Custom Camera View (Ep3 of Build a Custom Camera)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TqXrMnfJy8), only difference was the full screen camera view to my custom sized camera.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?

    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?

    var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()
    }

    func setupCaptureSession(){
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    }

    func setupDevice(){
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
        let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices

        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
                backCamera = device
            } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
                frontCamera = device
            }
        }

        currentCamera = frontCamera
    }

    func setupInputOutput(){
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format:[AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        } catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func setupPreviewLayer(){
        cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight
        cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.cameraView.bounds
    //    self.cameraView.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
        self.cameraView.layer.addSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!)
    }

    func startRunningCaptureSession(){
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling all your code from `viewDidLoad`. In `viewDidLoad` `autoLayout` hasn't taken effect yet soo your cameraPreviewLayer's size is whatever size you specified in the storyboard.

What you need to do update the "cameraPreviewLayer" bounds inside of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Something like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){

   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
   cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.cameraView.bounds
}
```

`Autolayout` is "applied" on views **after** `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called and that is called after `viewDidLoad`